# connecting http-conduit to xml-conduit

Tags: haskell, conduit, http-conduit

I'm struggling converting a Response from http-conduit to an XML document via xml-conduit.

The `doPost` function takes an XML Document and posts it to the server. The server responds with an XML Document.

```
doPost queryDoc = do
    runResourceT $ do

        manager <- liftIO $ newManager def
        req <- liftIO $ parseUrl hostname

        let req2 = req
                { method = H.methodPost
                , requestHeaders = [(CI.mk $ fromString "Content-Type", fromString "text/xml" :: Ascii) :: Header] 
                , redirectCount = 0
                , checkStatus = \_ _ -> Nothing
                , requestBody =  RequestBodyLBS $ (renderLBS def queryDoc)
                }

        res <- http req2 manager
        return $ res
```

The following works and returns '200':

```
let pingdoc = Document (Prologue [] Nothing []) (Element "SYSTEM" [] []) []
Response status headers body <- doPost pingdoc
return (H.statusCode status)
```

However, when I try and parse the Response body using xml-conduit, I run into problems:

```
Response status headers body <- doPost xmldoc
let xmlRes' = parseLBS def body
```

The resulting compilation error is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `L.ByteString'
            with actual type `Source m0 ByteString'
In the second argument of `parseLBS', namely `body'
In the expression: parseLBS def body
In an equation for `xmlRes'': xmlRes' = parseLBS def body
```

I've tried connecting the Source from http-conduit to the xml-conduit using $= and $$, but I'm not having any success.

Does anyone have any hints to point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Neil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `httpLbs` rather than `http`, so that it returns a lazy `ByteString` rather than a `Source` — the `parseLBS` function is named because that's what it takes: a **L**azy **B**yte**S**tring. However, it's probably best to use the conduit interface that the two are based on directly, as you mentioned. To do this, you should remove the `runResourceT` line from `doPost`, and use the following to get an XML document:

```
xmlRes' <- runResourceT $ do
    Response status headers body <- doPost xmldoc
    body $$ sinkDoc def
```

This uses xml-conduit's [`sinkDoc`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xml-conduit/latest/doc/html/Text-XML.html#v%3asinkDoc) function, connecting the `Source` from http-conduit to the `Sink` from xml-conduit.

Once they're connected, the complete pipeline has to be run using [`runResourceT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/conduit/latest/doc/html/Data-Conduit.html#v%3arunResourceT), which ensures all allocated resources are released in a timely fashion. The problem with your original code is that it runs the `ResourceT` too early, from inside `doPost`; you should generally use `runResourceT` right at the point that you want an actual result out, because a pipeline has to run entirely within the scope of a single `ResourceT`.

By the way, `res <- http req2 manager; return $ res` can be simplified to just `http req2 manager`.

Comment: That worked, with a minor tweak. I had to add the default parse settings after the sinkDoc:  `body $$ sinkDoc def`  Thanks so much!