# connecting an http-conduit source to the xml-conduit sink

Tags: haskell, conduit

I tried to follow along [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245342/) connecting-http-conduit-to-xml-conduit stackoverflow question, as it looks exactly like what I want to do.

I'm building off of the example from the [http-conduit](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/http-conduit) section of the yesod book.

The Code

```
getBody = do
   manager <- liftIO $ newManager def
   req <- liftIO $ parseUrl fredURL
   http req manager
```

The Error

```
No instance for (monad-control-0.3.1.3:Control.Monad.Trans.Control.MonadBaseControl
                   IO m0)
  arising from a use of `http'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (monad-control-0.3.1.3:Control.Monad.Trans.Control.MonadBaseControl
     IO m0)
In a stmt of a 'do' block: http req manager
In the expression:
  do { manager <- liftIO $ newManager def;
       req <- liftIO $ parseUrl fredURL;
       http req manager }
In an equation for `getBody':
    getBody
      = do { manager <- liftIO $ newManager def;
             req <- liftIO $ parseUrl fredURL;
             http req manager }
```

The Goal

I'm trying to return a Source that will be used by an xml-conduit Sink, the intent being that I want to use XML-Conduit to parse the XML and express it as a Haskell `data` type.
Could I get some elucidation as to why I am getting my error?

Comment: Can you put the code up somewhere? I'd guess that you're lacking a type signature. Turning on -XNoMonomorphismRestriction might help if you don't know what the type is supposed to be.

Comment: I added NoMonomorphismRestriction. It compiles now. Could you tell me why it's neccesary?

Comment: It's not necessary, adding a type signature will fix it too. Sometimes if I'm not writing type signatures first, I'll enable the `NoMonomorphismRestiction` and inspect the inferred type in GHCi... often times you can just copy & paste the type signature directly into your code and disable the NMR flag. There is a lot of information around on this subject, you can read about it here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction. Unfortunately the error message for these errors aren't terribly enlightening.

Comment: @NathanHowell you should post your comment as an answer, since it resolves the question.